# When using @Discordjs/voice to create players etc.it cannot find the correct dist folder to open indexes and thus throws an error:

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

```
`$ nodemon
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:571
      throw e;
      ^

'Error: Cannot find module 'E:\Bots\DgF Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\voice\dist\index.js'
     at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:15)
     at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:15)
     at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:565:14)
     at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:634:31)
     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
     at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Bots\DgF Bot\index.js:25:64)
     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '`E:\\Bots\\DgF Bot\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\voice\\package.json
    }'
```

I've tried creating a dist folder and inputting the voice indexes.
This instead gives the error:

```
`$ nodemon
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js
E:\Bots\DgF Bot\index.js:26
const player = createAudioPlayer();
               ^'

`TypeError: createAudioPlayer is not a function
     at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Bots\DgF Bot\index.js:26:16)
     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47`
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the discord.js and @dicordJs but to no avail.

The code block I am trying to get working is:

```
    const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');
    const { createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, StreamType } = require('@discordjs/voice');
    const player = createAudioPlayer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue tonight. I got it fixed with these commands:

```
$ sudo rm -rf node_modules
$ npm install
$ npm i @discordjs/voice@0.15
```

Hope this helps!